# Record a specific part in the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Inside my application, I need to access the camera to be opened inside the app. The goal is to record the part inside the box only as shown in the attached image

[image: Camera app inside my application]
So anyone has the idea how to do this ???

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/CropImageSample

Comment: Do you want to record record, as in a video, or simply take a snapshot/picture?

Answer (score 0):

You can't record the screen with any public API. Maybe you can try to record a video with UIImagePickerController and then cut the frames that you want.

Comment: What about rendering the view to images and writing those into a video using AVAssetWriter?

Comment: Could be another option. You need also to pay attention to performance.